# how to execute a php function from a separate php file onClick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have two php files (1.php and 2.php) linked with `require`

php.1 has a qr `<img src="http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=125x125&cht=qr&chl=<?php echo $_jattu; ?>" width="50%">` which gets its value from a string variable in 2.php `$_jattu;`

What I want is for `<?php echo $_jattu; ?>` to only echo when `<a class="w3-button2 w3-black2"></a>`  is clicked and not when the page is loaded or refreshed, what can I do to achieve this?

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: Could you give an indication of what you mean by "linked with `require`"? Sharing your code would help.

Comment: get it running with a simple link `href` and condition for `$_GET` in PHP, then think about javascript/ajax to make it without reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is imposible to do on the server side. Because the "onClick" event jumps on the client side when de user do the action.

You have few options.

- Enable another URL for load the content of $_jattu and when the user click load it with an AJAX request. Is the best way to do it and the result is more smooth and user friendly
- As you say you want to do it refreshing. So, slightly refresh the page with a new parameter on your url that tolds you that the "onClick" event has jump. Like:

  .../your/path?hasClick=true

And in your php code:

```
if(isset($_GET["hasClick"]) && $_GET["hasClick"]){
    echo $_jetty;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

if you want to remember that the user has clicked "forever" you can setup a cookie.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax. Make a request to whatever php script you want which will return $_jattu when clicking on the link. Then update your img link in javascript using the return of the ajax request.